# Why the selection is hidden after I was showing modeless dialog?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

If I have a selection in an edit control and I open a standard dialogue to find or replace, my selection becomes hidden, but when I close the modeless dialog, I can see my selection again.

```
hwndF = FindText(&fr); // open standart find modeless dialog
```

Breakdown of the problem:

1. I select text in edit control.

   [image]
2. I open find modeless dialog and cannot see the selection.

   [image]
3. I close the find modeless dialog and I can see my selection.

   [image]

After I open the modeless dialog I still want to see my selection.

Comment: How are we supposed to help without any code, attempts, or trace of literally anything.

Comment: What's the development environment? Visual Studio? Something else? Not much to go by here.

Answer (score 3):

To make sure the selected text is not hidden when the control loses focus, create the edit control with `ES_NOHIDESEL` style, for example `ES_NOHIDESEL | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD`. If using resource dialog, set "No hide selection = true".

See also:
[Edit Control Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464(v=vs.85).aspx)

> `ES_NOHIDESEL`
>  Negates the default behavior for an edit control.
>   The default behavior hides the selection when the control loses the
>   input focus and inverts the selection when the control receives the
>   input focus. If you specify `ES_NOHIDESEL`, the selected text is
>   inverted, even if the control does not have the focus.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's exactly so what I want.

Comment: @АлексейКуль: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)